# Automatically format .csv file upon download?

Tags: html, excel, csv, vba

I have a form that will open a file based on user's selections. A few files are .csv and those files open up in Excel, as expected. However, everything is placed into one cell... I know that there is a way to manually configure it so that the | or , are delimiters, but is there a way to set it so that Excel will automatically set the | as a delimiter?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you not arrange for the file to be delimited with a  comma if that's what Excel expects? Or give the users a choice so that they can choose a delimiter that matches their requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Because you use the word "download" and your question is tagged "html", I assume that the user interacts with a *web* form rather than a desktop form.

In that case, it's the web browser that decides what to do with the file. If the browser recognizes the `content-type` of the response as something it can handle natively (e.g. "text/plain" or "image/jpeg") then it may open the file and display it directly.

However if the content-type is not something it knows how to deal with (which is likely the case with "application/csv"), then it will download the file and ask the operating system to open it. At that point, the filename assigned to the file (which can be set via the HTTP response) may come into play.

On a Windows machine, the operating system maintains a list of file extensions and actions associated with those extensions. When you install Excel, that will normally make Excel the default "open" action for files with the ".csv" extension. That's why double-clicking on a ".csv" file opens in Excel, and also why it may open in Excel if you download it from a website. (If you didn't have Excel, it may simply ask you what program you want to use).

This is a long-winded way of saying that *if you had control over the user's machine* you could give the file a different file extension and then associate that extension with an action that did something different. But, I assume that you probably *don't* have that sort of control unless you're dealing only with in-house users, and anyway it would not be a trivial thing to achieve.

I don't think that there's any way to communicate to Excel *via the command line* that it should use a particular delimiter when opening a CSV file, and that - unfortunately - is the mechanism by which the operating system will ultimately open the file.

It *is* possible to control what Excel uses as the default delimiter for *all* CSV files (see https://superuser.com/a/606274/18472) but again that would require you to change the system-wide settings on your users' machines, which I imagine would not be possible.